# Problems with sorting multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I try to sort a multidimensional array in the way, so that the **elements with the same value should not being reordered**.

This is the given array, which should be sorted by the value of `type`:

```
$arr = array(

    "a" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "d" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "super" => array(
        "type" => 2
    ),
    "c" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "b" => array(
        "type" => 1
    )

);
```

The sorted array should be look like this:

```
Array
(
    [super] => Array
        (
            [type] => 2
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: use `arsort` to sort array.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: you have shown a strange expected array. Why keys should go in such order: 'a' - 'c' -'b' ? And why is 'd' key missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to improve your own answer to exclude inefficient `array_search()`. It is better to index array items before sorting, and use it for equal types.

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  $arr[$key]['index'] = $index;
  $index++;
}

uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['type'] < $b['type']) {
    return 1;
  } elseif ($a['type'] > $b['type']) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return $a['index'] - $b['index'];
  }
});

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  unset($arr[$key]['index']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that – I now use your solution. The only thing I had to add, was a additional `foreach` loop to remove `'index'` after sorting. Maybe you can update your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `uasort`: If you are still on PHP 5.2 or earlier, you'll have to define a sorting function first:

```
$myArray = array(

    "a" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "d" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "super" => array(
        "type" => 2
    ),
    "c" => array(
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "b" => array(
        "type" => 1
    )

);
function sortByOrder($a, $b)
{
    return $b['type'] - $a['type'];
}

uasort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
print_r($myArray);
```

Starting in PHP 5.3, you can use an anonymous function:

```
uasort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['type'] - $a['type'];
});
```

And finally with PHP 7 you can use the "spaceship operator":

```
uasort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
        return $b['type'] <=> $a['type'];
});
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [super] => Array
        (
            [type] => 2
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the output is not that what I want: The difference is, that I want to keep the order of the elements with the same type.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing through the post (How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?)[[How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php]), I found a solution for my problem.

If the types are equal, I sort the elements into a static order, which I get from a second value `id`.

#### Array to sort:

```
$array = array(

    "a" => array(
        "id" => "a",
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "c" => array(
        "id" => "c",
        "type" => 1
    ),
    "super" => array(
        "id" => "super",
        "type" => 2
    ),
    "b" => array(
        "id" => "b",
        "type" => 1
    )

);
```

#### Script:

```
$sort_keys = array_column($array, "id");

function cmp($a, $b){

    global $sort_keys;

    if ($a["type"] < $b["type"]) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($a["type"] > $b["type"]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return array_search($a["_id"], $sort_keys) - array_search($b["_id"], $sort_keys);
    }

}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

I do have the field `id` in my script already, so I don’t even have to change my array.

*Thanks to all who contribute to this post!*

Comment: Can you suppose your algorithm effectiveness in O-notaion?